# Why doesn't my showDateDialog() function change the Text() of the button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, state

I have a showDateDialog() function, for the user with a click on a button choose a moment, first chosing the date, and after it chosing the hours and minutes.
It does not change the value of the Text() of the button, but it changes the value of the variables.

I was expecting the button to change it's text when i confirm the date that i chose, but it only change the variables, the text keeps the same, even using the setState(( {}).

The function below is inside a "class GoogleMapsState extends State", the variables are out of it

```
DateTime selectedStartDate = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(hours: 12));
  DateTime selectedEndDate = DateTime.now();

  //Função para pegar o dia e a hora por meio de widgets específicos
  void showDateDialog() async {
    final startHour = selectedStartDate.hour;
    final startMinute = selectedStartDate.minute;
    final endHour = selectedEndDate.hour;
    final endMinute = selectedEndDate.minute;

    final selectedDates = await showDialog<List<DateTime>>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Center(child: Text('Informe o período do histórico desejado')),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text('Data inicial'),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text("${selectedStartDate.day}/${selectedStartDate.month}/${selectedStartDate.year}, às ${selectedStartDate.hour}:${selectedStartDate.minute}"),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await pickDate(selectedStartDate).then((date) async => {
                          if(date != null) {//Se não clicar em cancelar e a data for definida
                            await pickTime(TimeOfDay(hour: startHour, minute: startMinute)).then((time) => {
                              if(time != null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedStartDate = DateTime(
                                    date.year,
                                    date.month,
                                    date.day,
                                    time.hour,
                                    time.minute,
                                  );
                                  SnackBarHelper.showSnackBar(context, "Atualizou o valor: $selectedStartDate");
                                })
                              }
                            }),
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              const Text('Data final'),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text("${selectedEndDate.day}/${selectedEndDate.month}/${selectedEndDate.year}, às ${selectedEndDate.hour}:${selectedEndDate.minute}"),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await pickDate(selectedEndDate).then((date) async => {
                          if(date != null) {//Se não clicar em cancelar e a data for definida
                            await pickTime(TimeOfDay(hour: endHour, minute: endMinute)).then((time) => {
                              if(time != null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedEndDate = DateTime(
                                    date.year,
                                    date.month,
                                    date.day,
                                    time.hour,
                                    time.minute,
                                  );
                                })
                              }
                            }),
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Cancelar'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Confirmar'),
              onPressed: () {
                trackingStartMoment = selectedStartDate;
                trackingEndMoment = selectedEndDate;
                SnackBarHelper.showSnackBar(context, "Data inicial: ${trackingStartMoment.day}/${trackingStartMoment.month}/${trackingStartMoment.year}, às ${trackingStartMoment.hour}:${trackingStartMoment.minute}");
                SnackBarHelper.showSnackBar(context, "Data final: ${trackingEndMoment.day}/${trackingEndMoment.month}/${trackingEndMoment.year}, às ${trackingEndMoment.hour}:${trackingEndMoment.minute}");
                Navigator.of(context).pop([selectedStartDate, selectedEndDate]);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this with buttons in a stateful widget, so they can update their own state by themselves. Just use buttons that are stateful widgets, like the example below.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_maps/utils/image_helper.dart';

class PlayPauseButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(bool) togglePlayPause;
  final bool initialIsPlaying = false;

  const PlayPauseButton({Key? key, required this.togglePlayPause})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  PlayPauseButtonState createState() => PlayPauseButtonState();
}

class PlayPauseButtonState extends State<PlayPauseButton> {
  late bool isPlaying;
  late Future<Uint8List> playIconFuture;
  late Future<Uint8List> pauseIconFuture;

  Uint8List? playIcon;
  Uint8List? pauseIcon;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isPlaying = widget.initialIsPlaying;
    loadIcons();
  }

  Future<void> loadIcons() async {
    playIconFuture = ImageHelper.loadImage('assets/images/play_button.png', 100);
    pauseIconFuture = ImageHelper.loadImage('assets/images/pause_button.png', 100);

    playIcon = null;
    pauseIcon = null;

    final List<Uint8List> images = await Future.wait([playIconFuture, pauseIconFuture]);
    setState(() {
      playIcon = images[0];
      pauseIcon = images[1];
    });
  }

  void togglePlayPause() {
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = !isPlaying;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (pauseIcon != null && playIcon != null)
    ? IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        togglePlayPause(); //Altera o estado do isPlaying localmente
        widget.togglePlayPause(isPlaying); //Altera o estado do isPlaying no widget pai
      },
      icon: isPlaying
          ? Image.memory(pauseIcon!, fit: BoxFit.contain)
          : Image.memory(playIcon!, fit: BoxFit.contain),
    )
    : const CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```